# Date calculation conversion issues

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate a the date difference of `date - day` where the result is date format.

```
Update PermanentArrears set duedate =  Cast(convert(char(8),Datediff(Day, [arrearsdays], [WorkingDate])) As Date)
```

At some point I got the right result but I do not anymore. Here is the error message I receive:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using `dateadd` instead of `datediff`

EDIT: you don't need to convert - `dateadd` returns the same date format that is passed in

```
Update PermanentArrears 
    set duedate =  Dateadd(Day, [arrearsdays], [WorkingDate])
```

Comment: Same error.. besides that will give me the next date not the previous one, won't it?

Comment: Is `arrearsdays` the number of days to add to `WorkingDate` which will give you `duedate`?

Comment: No Duncan, WorkingDate -arrearsdays gives me duedate... so I solved it by changing the sign on the (arrearsdays)*-1. Thanks a bunch for your help!